# Iterar para dividir cada columna entre el primer item de la misma

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, bucles

Necesito saber como puede iterar los datos de cada columna, con referencia al primer dato de ella. Este sería mi DataFrame:

> ```
>                ARS=X       CLP=X    BRL=X
> Date                                      
> 2020-03-17  62.944099  852.799988  4.99900
> 2020-03-18  63.088402  847.799988  5.00970
> 2020-03-19  63.251400  867.500000  5.10396
> 2020-03-20  63.480099  861.799988  5.09420
> 2020-03-23  63.577000  860.500000  5.13140
> ```

Necesito que cada dato de `ars=x` sea divisible por el primero de ellos (`62.94`). Ejemplo, `63.48 / 62.94`, 6`3.57 / 62.94`, etc. Así con las columnas `clp` y `brl`.

Llegue a este `for`, pero multiplica todo por el mismo número, no me sirve así:

```
for col in graf:
    x = graf[col]*graf.iloc[0,0]
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te falta un nivel de iteración, iteras sobre las columnas pero no iteras sobre cada columna:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """\
Date            ARS=X       CLP=X    BRL=X                            
2020-03-17  62.944099  852.799988  4.99900
2020-03-18  63.088402  847.799988  5.00970
2020-03-19  63.251400  867.500000  5.10396
2020-03-20  63.480099  861.799988  5.09420
2020-03-23  63.577000  860.500000  5.13140
"""

graf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep="\s+", index_col="Date")          

for col in graf:
    print(f"\nColumna {col}")
    first = graf.at[graf.index[0], col]
    for row in graf.loc[graf.index[1]:, col]:
        x = row * first
        print(x)
```

> ```
> Columna ARS=X
> 3971.0426212397983
> 3981.3023834886
> 3995.697635985801
> 4001.796982123
>
> Columna CLP=X
> 723003.8195928003
> 739803.9895900001
> 734943.0194248003
> 733834.3896740001
>
> Columna BRL=X
> 25.043490299999995
> 25.514696039999997
> 25.465905799999998
> 25.6518686
> ```

No obstante, puedes aplicar la operación in-place o generar nuevas columnas vectorizando la operación sobre cada columna:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

data = """\
Date            ARS=X       CLP=X    BRL=X                            
2020-03-17  62.944099  852.799988  4.99900
2020-03-18  63.088402  847.799988  5.00970
2020-03-19  63.251400  867.500000  5.10396
2020-03-20  63.480099  861.799988  5.09420
2020-03-23  63.577000  860.500000  5.13140
"""
graf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep="\s+", index_col="Date")          

for col in graf:
    graf[f"{col}_mul"] = (
        graf.loc[graf.index[1]:, col] * graf.at[graf.index[0], col]
        )
```

> ```
> >>> graf
>
>                 ARS=X       CLP=X    BRL=X    ARS=X_mul      CLP=X_mul  BRL=X_mul
> Date                                                                             
> 2020-03-17  62.944099  852.799988  4.99900          NaN            NaN        NaN
> 2020-03-18  63.088402  847.799988  5.00970  3971.042621  723003.819593  25.043490
> 2020-03-19  63.251400  867.500000  5.10396  3981.302383  739803.989590  25.514696
> 2020-03-20  63.480099  861.799988  5.09420  3995.697636  734943.019425  25.465906
> 2020-03-23  63.577000  860.500000  5.13140  4001.796982  733834.389674  25.651869
> ```

En la pregunta mencionas que quieres dividir entre el primer elemento de cada fila y en el código multiplicas, no obstante la idea es la misma, solo cambiar el operador.

El uso de `io.StringIO` y `pandas.read_csv` es solo para emular tu ejemplo.